# Convert raster to a matrix

Tags: image-processing, raster, r-raster

I can read an image, raster, limit the values from 10-100. What I can't do is convert the limitation to a matrix where I could sum all values.

```
library(raster)

DEM <- raster("img.JPG")

image(DEM, zlim=c(10,100))
```

I'd like to convert the result of

```
image(DEM, zlim=c(10,60))
```

into a matrix where I can perform calculations.

`image(DEM, zlim=c(10,60))` would result in 
[image]

Target is to only sum the Red Circle.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(raster)
d <- raster("img.JPG")
dd <- reclassify(d, rbind(c(-Inf, 10, NA), c(60, Inf, NA)))
# or:  d[d< 10 | d > 60] <- NA
plot(dd)
hist(dd)
```

Or, if you really want a matrix

```
m <- matrix(d)
m[m<10] <- NA
```